# New to SharePoint and looked at the sync problems

Tags: file-upload

I am new to this site  and I am learning about SharePoint that my employer has on their internet.

When I synced my folder to the SharePoint and it had 12 items that can't be sync. My questions is when I looked at them and it showed me that .mdb files are not upload these files. What is the main reason for that to block it ?

These .mdb are files that hold the database that I use for my GIS project. This purpose for me to upload is to backup my project.

Is there a way around to keep them ? Would Zip these files be acceptable to upload them ?

Answer (score 0):

[This site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262496.aspx) shows all the different file types that are blocked by default.  Zip files do not seem to be blocked, so they may be an acceptable alternative unless your company has specifically blocked them.

Microsoft does not specifically state why MDB files are blocked, but it could be that somehow Internet Explorer would have a way of executing or opening the files:

> By default, many file types are blocked, including file types that are treated as executable by Internet Explorer.